# Should I include page numbers with landscape?

Tags: longtable, landscape

In my paper I have two separate `longtables` that each go across 3 pages in `landscape` mode.

Which is typographically better (i) include page numbers in the bottom center of these tables (ii) have no page numbers under these tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If the numbers might get confused with the table it might be best to drop the numbers, but if it's a loose leaf document and people might drop the pages, best to keep the numbers so the pages can be put back in order.

Comment: Do you have any clue about what journals `tend` to prefer?

Comment: No. (I've been out of the journal submission loop for some decades:-)